# Why Votes on meta.stackoverflow.com do not affect reputation of User but that is not the case with meta.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

Just observed that Votes on meta.stackoverflow.com do not affect reputation but User reputation gets affected by upvotes/downvotes on meta.stackexchange.com

What is the specific reason behind this?

Here it is from Help section of meta.stackoverflow.com:

If you have an account on Stack Overflow, you have an account on its meta site.

*You do not need to create a separate account for meta; once you are logged in on Stack Overflow, you are also logged in and may post on its meta site.

Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.*

Comment: History lesson, MSE used to be MSO.  MSO was the first meta site in the network and was created as a separate site with its own reputation. Since then, all SE sites got their own child meta sites (except SO).  It wasn't until about April 2014 when MSO was split off to become this site.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Much of this is historical.  I wasn't around for the earliest days, so I might not have the exact right order of some of the original events, but it basically was just how the meta sites evolved.

- In the beginning, there was no meta at all.  Meta discussion did not exist on a separate site (meta questions were asked on the main site, which meant that users earned rep from their "meta" posts, although meta posts appear to have been discouraged to some extent).
- But it was discovered there was a need, so Meta Stack Overflow was created.  There was no such thing as a "child" meta site like there is today.  It was simply launched as a new stand-alone site with its own reputation.  The "valuable" legacy meta posts from the main site were migrated over.
- As time past, Stack Overflow expanded to Super User, and Server Fault, then the rest of the network slowly evolved.
- Individual meta sites were created for each of the other sites.  On those meta sites, the behavior was exactly like what is mentioned in the help center - privileges and reputation was inherited from the main site.  Meta Stack Overflow remained the sole exception because it was already there, and had also evolved as the defacto Meta.StackExchange (even though it was not called that)<sup>1</sup>.
- In early 2014, Meta.SO and Meta.SE were finally split.  The old Meta.SO was removed and replaced with the current site.  Some SO specific content was migrated.  The remaining content was left on the site and it was rebranded Meta.StackExchange.

So the simple answer is the reason reputation on Meta.StackExchange is because that is how the site originally existed.  It was (and still is) a standalone StackExchange site, and not a child meta site.

<sup>1</sup> - If you want to read more about some of the decisions on why the child meta's evolved like they did (tied to the parent site's reputation), you can read about it in the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta/63235#63235) [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311645/why-votes-on-meta-stackoverflow-com-do-not-affect-reputation-of-user-but-that-is#comment279287_311663) linked in the comments.

But to paraphrase [Jaydles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147336/jaydles), there are 2 key points he makes in that post:

- ***...the most "trust" to define the site's culture should be assigned to those that have earned the most trust on the site itself; they are its culture.*** - So this is why child meta reputation is tied to the parent site's reputation
- ***On a site about the engine, it does not make as much sense to make the reputation mirror one or some of the other sites.*** - this is why MSE has its own reputation.  There is nothing to really tie your reputation to that would be reflective of the system's trust in you since your reputation on other sites does not really mean that you understand how SE actually works.

Comment: "On a site about _the engine_, it does not make as much sense to make the reputation mirror one or some of the other sites..." ([Should reputation from SO carry over to Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63235/165773))