# Why aren't points given to content on Meta?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason that points aren't awarded to the users for the activity generated on Meta. Why isn't it like Stack Overflow where questions with upvotes gain the user asking points?

Comment: Related: [Why Votes on meta.stackoverflow.com do not affect reputation of User but that is not the case with meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311645/why-votes-on-meta-stackoverflow-com-do-not-affect-reputation-of-user-but-that-is)

Comment: Because [Meta is Murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) and this kind of behaviour is frowned upon?

Comment: You speak only of upvotes, but there is also the opposite: downvotes. On meta people downvote generally to indicate disagreement, should someone lose points because people disagree with them? Hell no, that would shy people away from asking the hard questions or making feature requests.